# Why Will My Script Not Print Errors?? Using JS and MongoDB in Replit

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

So, recently I've been working on this school project. Nothing too much honestly, as I am not completely fluent in js. But I ran into this [tutorial](https://www.codementor.io/@garethdwyer/building-a-crm-app-with-nodejs-repl-it-and-mongodb-119r72mczg) when trying to use the MongoDB database for my site.
After following the guide up to the point where the simple database is finished, there seem to be errors in my code. But for some reason, no errors are being printed, making it very difficult to work on. Here is an example of some of my files:

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = 0000;
const socket = require('socket.io');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const Users = require('./public/UserModel.js');
let rooms = [];

app.use(express.static('./public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const mongo_username = process.env.MONGO_USERNAME
const mongo_password = process.env.MONGO_PASSWORD
const uri = "mongodb+srv://Killerswordsman9776:<password>@cluster0.r92qc.mongodb.net/Cluster0?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

console.log("grabbed link");

const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
let http = require('http').Server(app);

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || server);
http.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  
  app.post('/index', function (req, res, next) {
    client.connect(err => {
      const users = client.db("crmdb").collection("users");
      let user = { name: req.body.name, email: req.body.email, note: req.body.note };
      users.insertOne(user, function(err, res) {
        if (err) concole.log("{error}");
        console.log("1 user inserted");
      });
    })
  })
      console.log('listening on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

script.js

```
  input = document.createElement('textarea');
  input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
  input.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Message');
  document.body.appendChild(input);
  sendBtn = createButton('Send Message');
  sendBtn.mousePressed(send);
  del = createButton('Delete Messages');
  del.mousePressed(deleteMess);
  createP('');
  info = '<strong><u>Messages:</u></strong><br/>';
  output = document.createElement('iframe');
  output.setAttribute('scrolling', 'auto');
  output.setAttribute('srcdoc', info);
  output.setAttribute('title', 'messages');
  document.body.appendChild(output);
  socket.on('message', (data, color) => {
    info += `<strong>${data.handle}</strong>: ${data.value} || <i>${hr}:${min} ${time}</i><br>`;
    output.setAttribute('srcdoc', info);
  });
}
function send() {
  data = {
    value: input.value,
    handle: username.value
  }
  socket.emit('message', data);


}

function deleteMess() {
  info = '<strong><u>Messages:</u></strong><br/>';
}

function joining() {
  if (room.value != '') {
    socket.emit('join', room.value);
  } else {
    socket.emit('join', 'Default Room');
  }
}

function draw() {
  hr = hour();
  min = minute();

  if (hr / 12 > 1) {
    hr -= 12;
    time = 'PM';
  } else {
    time = 'AM';
  }


}
```

If any other files need viewing, or I'm not including enough information, please let me know and I will fix that. But the main problem I have here is just to get my errors printing. Thx

Comment: "*no errors are being printed*" If this is the case, can you elaborate on exactly how you reached the conclusion that "*there seem to be errors in my code*"?

Comment: Well if the code is not functioning properly, i assume its not working and has errors :/

Comment: Something "*having errors*" and something simply not working as expected are definitely very different things and are not mutually inclusive. (For instance, you can write a completely syntactically correct `function`, but never call it - while there are no "*errors*", the code is not functioning to the intended specification/requirements.) Further, "*not functioning properly*" is extremely vague and can encompass a whole host of situations; can you provide clarity in your question as to what behavior you're specifically observing, and what you expect this code to do instead? [ask]

Comment: That is a very good point actually. Shown in my html file better, Its main function is to login and chat. The server seems connected and running fine but none of my messages save or send. Not sure which or if even that. https://texting.kirit0.repl.co/ Here is the link for my bit broken site but here you can check it out